# NSUserDefaults causes app reject

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval

Apple testers have been rejected our app due violating of guideline:

> [2.23 Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected]

Since we have stored our database files without the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` flag - it was backed up in the iCloud - and caused the reject.

So, we added the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` flag to our files, and it decreased the amount of data stored in the iCloud.

BUT - we realized that NSUserDefaults also takes some amount of space in the iCloud.
We are using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and we don't have much control of it.

If we go to *`device->settings->iCloud->Storage`* & *`BackUP->Manage Storage`*, we can see that our app still takes 0.5 kb of data in the iCloud, because of using NSUserDefaults.
(removing the uses of NSUserDefaults in the code will decrease it to 0 - no data)

**Will Apple reject our app again for the NSUserDefaults takes data in the iCloud?**

Comment: No, it is expected that applications will use `NSUserDefaults`, how much space were your other files taking up and where were they stored?

Comment: The app used 2.4 MB of space. Now it takes between 0.4kb to 0.8kb.

Comment: I can see now a warning in the code: WARNING: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Donno-Info.plist file 'Donno-Info.plist'. I see that it copied the plist from the bundle. We already sent the app the Apple that way, do you think they will reject the app for that reason? (it might double the amount of NSUserDefaults space)..

Comment: After sending our app to a review in Apple we have realized that we have this warning in the code:

"WARNING: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Donno-Info.plist file..."

Since it might actually double the plist file,- will Apple reject the app due using unnecessary space in the iCloud?

(we have already been rejected first time because of storing our database files without the DO_NOT_BACKUP flag)

Thanks.

Comment: Your main plist file should not be in copy bundle resources.

Comment: @igoren what happenned with your app? I'm in an really similar situation - curious if 400 bytes will be a problem.

Comment: I'd not worry too much about `appname-info.plist` being included to `copy resources` stage as it's at the bundle anyway named as `info.plist`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any amount of data in NSUserDefaults in your app and you will not get rejected. I'm not sure what the max data is for it, but I don't recall Apple specifying a limit. There is however a limit to the iCloud defaults settings. You can back up your NSUserDefaults to iCloud, but there is a strict 1Mb limit for data saved there. So be mindful of how large your data gets when saved there.

Comment: But NSUserDefaults is also not intended for arbitrary data storage. It's intended for preferences and settings only.